# Cocos2d App not Loading into Jailbroken 2G ipod

Tags: ios, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I have a Jailbroken 2G device with iOS version 4.2
& using xcode4 with Cocos2d 2.0.

I am able to load & run my sample test Apps into the device.
But in case of Cocos2d Apps, the Application is not Loaded in the device. No issue, no error- but the app is not there in the ipod.

The build settings are set to armv6 & iOS deployment target to 4.2, like the other Apps.

But the only difference is-
in the Cocos2d App info.plist, cant find the Architecture( armv6/armv7) in 'Required device capabilities'- which needs to be set to armv6.

Is the Cocos2d 2.0 meant to run only in armv7! If not, then how can I change the info.plist
 Architecture to armv6?

Or is there anything, which needs to be done? Please help.

*In the attached image, you can see- there is no architecture defined in the 'Required device capabilities' section.*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cocos2d version 2.0 supports only the below listed device(s)

- iPad 1, iPad 2, iPad 3,iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPod Touch 3 and iPod Touch 4 ARE
  supported

For more information Please go to the [website](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3amigrate_to_v2.0) and check the devices list.

Comment: +1 Thanks man. You r right. I checked out with Cocos2d 1.0.1, and worked fine. Thanks again.